# What is the difference between Knowledge Representation and Automated Reasoning?

Tags: terminology, comparison, knowledge-representation, automated-reasoning

Knowledge Representation and Automated Reasoning are two AI subfields which seem to have something to do with reasoning. 
However, I can't find any information online about their relationship. Are they synonyms? Is KR a subfield of AR? What's the difference, if any?

To expand further, I believe representing knowledge is an essential part of "reasoning": how can you reason without a proper representation of the concepts you want to manipulate?
At the same time, reasoning seems to be an essential part of KR (we build Knowledge Bases in order to build computer programs which are able to make inferences from them).

So it seems to me that they are the same field, or at least deeply interrelated, but nobody on the internet seems to explicitly say that; furthermore, in [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5782/were-the-requirements-to-solve-the-turing-test-in-ai-a-modern-approach-forese) question, they are mentioned separately.

Another point of ambiguity is that the wikipedia page of [KRR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_representation_and_reasoning) mentions reasoning and automated reasoning as a part of KR; it even lists "automated theorem proving" (a classical application of AR) as an application of KR.
But at the same time, we have a separate [AR page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_reasoning) which does not mention KR at all.